# Stopping Camel route when no messages in queue (jms, seda)

Tags: apache-camel

I have a Camel route that moves messages from a jms queue to another. That route is by default stopped and it is started by a call to a jetty route using controlBus.

As I need to move the messages on demand, once the source jms queue is empty, I need to disable the "mover" route, so messages that arrive later are not processed until the "mover" route is activated again.

Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to obtain the queue message count using `JmsTemplate` and then shutting down the route from another thread using a processor. Downsides might be a dependency to `org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate` and some [gotchas](https://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas) related to it.

```java
package com.example;

import java.util.Collections;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.ServiceStatus;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate;

public class QueueConsumerTests extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

    @Test
    public void stopesQueueListenerRouteAfterConsumingAllMessages() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint jmsMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:jmsMockEndpoint");
        jmsMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(5);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            template.sendBody("direct:test", "Message " + i);
        }
        context().getRouteController().startRoute("queueListener");

        Thread.sleep(5000);

        ServiceStatus routeStatus = context().getRouteStatus("queueListener");
        assertEquals(routeStatus, ServiceStatus.Stopped);
        jmsMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory);

        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                from("direct:test")
                    .to("jms:queue:test");

                from("jms:queue:test")
                    .routeId("queueListener")    
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .log("message from queue: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:jmsMockEndpoint")
                    .setBody().exchange(e -> {

                        int messageCount = jmsTemplate.browse("test", (session, browser) -> {
                            return Collections.list(browser.getEnumeration()).size();
                        });
                        return messageCount;
                    })
                    .filter(body().isEqualTo(0))
                        .to("seda:stopPolling")
                    .end();

                    from("seda:stopPolling?concurrentConsumers=1&multipleConsumers=false")
                        .log("stop polling")
                        .process(e -> e.getContext().getRouteController().stopRoute("queueListener"))
                        .setProperty("stopped").constant(false)
                        .loopDoWhile(exchangeProperty("stopped").isEqualTo(false))
                            .delay(100)
                            .setProperty("stopped").exchange(e -> { 
                                return e.getContext().getRouteStatus("queueListener").isStopped();
                            })
                        .end()
                        .log("stopped queueListener");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        context.addComponent("jms", jmsComponent);
        return context;
    }
}
```

Alternative could be to use `timer` with `poll-enrich` with timeout and shutdown the route if it results in null body. This however is slower and possibly less robust due to how you need to specify frequency of polling and timeout.

```java
package com.example;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
import org.apache.activemq.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQBroker;
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.RoutesBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.ServiceStatus;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent;
import org.apache.camel.component.mock.MockEndpoint;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class QueueConsumerTests2 extends CamelTestSupport {
    
    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQBroker broker = new EmbeddedActiveMQBroker();

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(
            "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");

    @Test
    public void stopesQueueListenerRouteAfterConsumingAllMessages() throws Exception {

        MockEndpoint jmsMockEndpoint = getMockEndpoint("mock:jmsMockEndpoint");
        jmsMockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(5);

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            template.sendBody("direct:test", "Message " + i);
        }
        context().getRouteController().startRoute("queueListener");

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        ServiceStatus routeStatus = context().getRouteStatus("queueListener");
        assertEquals(routeStatus, ServiceStatus.Stopped);
        jmsMockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }

    @Override
    protected RoutesBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                
                from("direct:test")
                    .to("jms:queue:test");

                from("timer:moverTimer?period=500")
                    .routeId("queueListener")  
                    .autoStartup(false)
                    .pollEnrich("jms:queue:test", 1000)
                    .choice()
                        .when(body().isNotNull())
                            .log("message from queue: ${body}")
                            .to("mock:jmsMockEndpoint")
                        .otherwise()
                            .to("seda:stopPolling")
                    .end();

                    from("seda:stopPolling?concurrentConsumers=1&multipleConsumers=false")
                        .log("stop polling")
                        .process(e -> e.getContext().getRouteController().stopRoute("queueListener"))
                        .setProperty("stopped").constant(false)
                        .loopDoWhile(exchangeProperty("stopped").isEqualTo(false))
                            .delay(100)
                            .setProperty("stopped").exchange(e -> { 
                                return e.getContext().getRouteStatus("queueListener").isStopped();
                            })
                        .end()
                        .log("stopped queueListener");
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected CamelContext createCamelContext() throws Exception {
        
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        JmsComponent jmsComponent = new JmsComponent();
        jmsComponent.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
        context.addComponent("jms", jmsComponent);
        return context;
    }
}
```

**Now as a disclaimer** haven't tested these patterns thoroughly so there might be some edge cases (and better ways to do this). There's also the fact that Camel [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/manual/faq/how-can-i-stop-a-route-from-a-route.html#HowcanIstoparoutefromaroute-Usingathreadtostoparoutefromaroute) uses `java.lang.Thread` to stop route inside a processor instead of using `seda` consumer so there might be something in to that.

Use of `Thread.sleep` in unit test is also quite messy and not something I would recommend unless you just want to quickly experiment on something with camel.

**Used Dependencies:**

- org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.24.2
- org.apache.camel/camel-jms/2.24.2

**Test scope:**

- org.apache.camel/camel-test/2.24.2
- org.apache.activemq.tooling/activemq-junit/5.16.3
- org.apache.activemq/activemq-broker/5.16.3

Comment: The timer solution it's an easy way to implement it. Thanks!

Comment: for some weird reason the pollEnrich always timeouts with AMQP (which I am testing with, azure service bus). I'm not getting why.

Comment: You'll have to provide poll-enrich the same configuration you'd provide for consumer endpoint (`from`). Also the 1000ms is quite short duration for timeout, you might want to increase that.

Comment: I did, url looks exactly the same as the from on another route (I used pollEnrich before). I ended up doing an intermediary seda route, and the pollEnrich points to the seda. That's actually working. Thanks!